# Can this be simplified with Lambda/Block initialization?

Tags: c#, initialization, expression, member-initialization

Been bouncing back and forth between Swift and C# and I'm not sure if I'm forgetting certain things, or if C# just doesn't easily support what I'm after.

Consider this code which calculates the initial value for `Foo`:

```
// Note: This is a field on an object, not a local variable.
int Foo = CalculateInitialFoo();

static int CalculateInitialFoo() {
    int x = 0;
    // Perform calculations to get x
    return x;
}
```

Is there any way to do something like this without the need to create the separate one-time-use function and instead use an instantly-executing lambda/block/whatever?

In Swift, it's simple. You use a closure (the curly-braces) that you instantly execute (open and closed parentheses), like this:

```
int Foo = {
    int x = 0
    // Perform calculations to get x
    return x
}()
```

It's clear, concise and doesn't clutter up the object's interface with functions just to initialize fields.

*Note: To be clear, I do **NOT** want a calculated property. I am trying to initialize a member field which requires multiple statements to do completely.*

Comment: What is Foo? is it a field, a property or something else? The context matters when suggesting alternative syntax.

Comment: @SelmanGenç "*It is a member field*"

Comment: What's the advantage you're trying to gain by not using a method? Wouldn't something like this be simple and easy to use?     public class FooClass
    {
        public int Foo { get; set; } = InitFoo();

        private static int InitFoo() { int x = 0; return x; }
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the problem in the general case you'd need to create and then execute an anonymous function, which you can technically do as an expression:

```
int Foo = new Func<int>(() => 
    {
        int x = 0;
        // Perform calculations to get x
        return x;
    })();
```

You can clean this up a bit by writing a helper function:

```
public static T Perform<T>(Func<T> function)
{
    return function();
}
```

Which lets you write:

```
int Foo = Perform(() => 
    {
        int x = 0;
        // Perform calculations to get x
        return x;
    });
```

While this is better than the first, I think it's pretty hard to argue that *either* is better than just writing a function.

In the non-general case, many specific implementations can be altered to run on a single line rather than multiple lines.  Such a solution may be possible in your case, but we couldn't possibly say without knowing what it is.  There will be cases where this is *possible* but undesirable, and cases where this may actually be preferable.  Which are which is of course subjective.

Comment: I like this the best so far.  Your `Perform` function gets me almost to where I need to be in C# and I can include that in a global scope somewhere.  I'll give it a little more time, but I think this is the solution I'll use.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't suggest doing this, but you could use an anonymous function to initialize

```
int _foo = new Func<int>(() =>
{
    return 5;
})();
```

Is there a reason you would like to do it using lambdas rather than named functions, or as a calculated property?

I assume you want to avoid calculated properties because you want to either modify the value later, or the computation is expensive and you want to cache the value.

```
int? _fooBacking = null;

int Foo
{
    get
    {
        if (!_fooBacking.HasValue)
        {
            _fooBacking = 5;
        }

        return _fooBacking.Value;
    }
    set
    {
        _fooBacking = value;
    }
}
```

This will use what you evaluate in the conditional the first time it is gotten, while still allowing the value to be assigned.

If you remove the setter it will turn it into a cached calculation. Be careful when using this pattern, though. Side-effects in property getters will be frowned upon because they make the code difficult to follow.

Comment: Your deferred execution implementation isn't thread safe, while the OP's is.  That may or may not be a requirement for any given case, but it's an important difference.  Also note that in the OP's case they're not actually deferring execution, they're simply trying to avoid creating a named function that's callable at any time, when it's only ever designed to be used in one place.

Comment: To answer, it's a multi-statement initialization of an object.  That's why we don't want to use a function, it can be called elsewhere, even if set private.  Plus, that clutters up the object's API. We also don't want a calculated property because that executes every time, meaning we'd be constantly initializing new objects instead of getting back our other instance. It's just not as clean as Swift, but your first answer is close enough that I may accept this.

Comment: @MarqueIV If it doesn't need to be thread-safe, the deferred execution implementation (the second one) will only run once, and you can remove the setter to make it readonly. It is also more conventionally "C#" than the anonymous function initializer.

Comment: Yeah, I'm familiar with that pattern. It's just after using c# since its inception, then Swift for the past two years, I've come to appreciate the syntactic elegance of the latter.  Compare both of your examples with what I've updated in the original question where I show the Swift code.  I guess I'm just spoiled.

Comment: @MarqueIV I see what you mean. I'm also a sucker for pretty things, and that does look really nice in swift.

Answer (score 0):

You could initialize your field in the constructor and declare `CalculateInitialFoo` as local function.

```
private int _foo;

public MyType()
{
    _foo = CalculateInitialFoo();

     int CalculateInitialFoo()
     {
          int x = 0;
          // Perform calculations to get x
          return x;
     }
}
```

This won't change your code too much but you can at least limit the scope of the method to where it's only used.